# Behavior of Location Services prompt

Tags: iphone

I'm using the location services in my application. According to theory I need to get the popup message to use the location services. If we say yes then it will be proceeded.

1. But if we say no it has to ask once you'll run the app again. But it's not happening
2. If I install the application at very first time I'm able to get the popup message, but if I delete that and reinstalled the app at that time I'm not getting it.

I'm so confused with the behavior of the location services in iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

I think that once the user has said no, if they want to change their mind they need to go into `Settings -> Location Services` and turn it on from there.

Comment: and to add to this, the preferences aren't deleted on app deletion. A SO question came up on this recently but I am unable to get that link.

Comment: any how when ever i am running my app i need get the popup when i say .according to theory but its not happening is it a ios behaviour

Comment: when i say no in the above comment